# Running a UDF in Excel that returns a SQL query in a macro

Tags: sql, excel, vba

The first block of code is a UDF that I use to run SQL queries and updates based on values in spreadsheets. It functions effectively as a formula within the spreadsheet. The bottom block attempts to use the UDF in a macro to execute a query and obtain a count of records, but I am struggling with the correct syntax. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
Function SqlExec(SqlStmt As String, Trigger As Integer)

Dim CString As String

CString = _
    "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;" & _
    "Password=P@ssw0rd;" & _
    "Persist Security Info=True;" & _
    "User ID=sa;Initial Catalog=GlasPacLX_Testdb;" & _
    "Data Source=192.168.19.110\gts;" & _
    "Use Procedure for Prepare=1;" & _
    "Auto Translate=True;" & _
    "Packet Size=4096;" & _
    "Workstation ID=TWOSEATER;" & _
    "Use Encryption for Data=False;" & _
    "Tag with column collation when possible=False"

Trigger = Sheets("Code").Range("Trigger").Value

If Trigger = 1 Then

Dim Cn As ADODB.Connection, Rs As ADODB.Recordset
    
    Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set Rs = New ADODB.Recordset

Cn.Open CString
Rs.Open SqlStmt, Cn, adOpenForwardOnly
SqlExec = Rs.GetRows
Rs.Close
Set Rs = Nothing
Cn.Close
Set Cn = Nothing

End If

End Function
```

Below is the macro I'm attempting to use to execute a query and show the results in a message box. The query returns an integer. The macro doesn't work (byref argument type mismatch). Any ideas for fixing it?

```
Sub SqlExecCount()

Trigger = 1
SqlStmt = "SELECT COUNT(DocumentNumber) FROM Document"

MsgBox SqlExec(SqlStmt, Trigger)

End Sub
```

Comment: `Rs.GetRows` returns a 2-D array: you can't display that directly using `MsgBox `

Answer (score 1):

`Rs.GetRows` returns a 2-D array: you can't display that directly using `MsgBox`

Try something like:

```
MsgBox SqlExec(SqlStmt, Trigger)(0, 0)
```

The array from `GetRows` is zero-based - the first dimension is the field index, and the second is the data row index.